# How to Increasing the Registry parameter Size Limit

Tags: c#, windows, internet-explorer, registry, regedit

I want to open a windows application via InternetExplorer/Edge . For that I have created a registry entry in reg edit with the help of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx.

Everything is working here if I pass the request which is less than 507 character.
 I want to pass the request values which is more than 507 ,then its not opening the application at all.Can anyone help me to increase the limit.
**example**: in reg edit I have set it up as

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
  alert
  (Default) = "URL:Alert Protocol"
  URL Protocol = ""
  DefaultIcon
     (Default) = "alert.exe,1"
  shell
     open
        command
           (Default) = "C:\Program Files\Alert\alert.exe" "%1"
```

in browser I am calling like

```
alert:xxxxxxxxxxxx.....xxx (alert:less than 507 char)- is working fine.
alert:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.....xxxx(alert:more than 507 char )- not working.
```

thanks,

Comment: Can you show an example of an input that is >  500 characters? Is `alert.exe` your program?

Comment: What is `alert.exe` doing? Maybe it's that app that has an input limit?

Comment: @mjwills ; I can, but as the number indicate it will be a bigger string . Actually it will be a Json Object.

Comment: @René Vogt ; It doesn't matter because the request even not reaching in alert.exe  .

Comment: ex:I am considering you have installed skype .You can try this in IE.
skype:ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwweeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeellllllllllllllllllllllllllps -  will work

Comment: skype:ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwweeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeellllllllllllllllllllllllllpss -- will not work